# How can I remove Tight Coupling in SpringBoot with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm a beginner with Spring boot/JPA and I'm trying to remove tight coupling from my code in one method, apparently the only solution that worked was the tight coupled code, but it's a bad practice.
So I have an entity called User and one called Location. TL DR User has an array of locations with objects, basically:
`{id: "12f4", userId: "1", name: "haus", latitude: "12", longitude: "34"}`

The problem relies on the Location Entity. I have this location entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID locationId;

    private String locationName;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;


    GETTERS AND SETTERS...

        public UUID getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(UUID userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
```

Then I have my repository LocationRespository

```
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, UUID>{
}
```

After that I have my LocationService (interface)

```
public interface LocationService {
    Location createLocation(Location location, UUID userId);
    List<Location> getAllLocations();
    ... rest of the code
}
```

After that I have my LocationServiceImpl (Class)

```
@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {
    private final LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public LocationServiceImpl(LocationRepository locationRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Location createLocation(Location location, UUID userId) {
        HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        location.setUserId(userId);
        return this.locationRepository.save(location);
    }
```

and my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/locations")
public class LocationController {
    private final LocationService locationService;

    @Autowired
    public LocationController(LocationService locationService) {
        this.locationService = locationService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/create/{userId}")
    public Location createLocation(@PathVariable("userId") UUID userId, @RequestBody Location location) {
        return locationService.createLocation(location, userId);
    }
```

How can I remove this bad code from here: (Service Impl)

```
location.setUserId(userId);
```

In the case I'm using postman and I'm passing in the uri the userId like:
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/locations/create/b7999c24-8d80-4560-aead-5d801e833e0b

Also I have a body like:
{
"locationName": "Darmstadt zwei",
"latitude": "1321234",
"longitude": "4256363"
}

The only problem is to remove the Tight Coupled code, because It's calling a setter from my entity directly into the Service.
How can I solve this?

Comment: And how is that tightly coupling it to JPA? It is just calling a method on an Object. That object is in this case using JPA, but that could have been something else entirely. Not sure what makes you think this tightly couples it to JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, before removing the setter, can find a problem in directly using the Location **entity** as @RequestBody in the API(Controller).

- Reason: If you use an entity directly as an API parameter, when the entity changes, the API specification also changes.

  - It is not good to have strong coupling between entity and API specification. This can be solved by using DTO (Data Transfer Object).

Additionally, returning an entity directly as the return type of the **controller** causes the same problem, and if there is a two-way relationship(eg. @ManyToOne and @OneToMany...), recursion occurs and StackOverFlow occurs.

- I will present my solution below.

```java
//DTO(Data Transfer Object)
public record LocationCreateRequest(
        String locationName,
        String latitude,
        String longitude
) {
}
```

```java
public record LocationCreateRepsonse(
        String id,
        String locationName,
        String latitude,
        String longitude
) {
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/locations")
public class LocationController {
    private final LocationService locationService;

    @Autowired
    public LocationController(LocationService locationService) {
        this.locationService = locationService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/create/{userId}")
    public LocationCreateRepsonse createLocation(@PathVariable("userId") UUID userId, @RequestBody LocationCreateRequest request) {
        return locationService.createLocation(request, userId);
    }
}
```

Now let's delete the setter.

```java
@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {
    private final LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public LocationServiceImpl(LocationRepository locationRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public LocationCreateResponse createLocation(LocationCreateRequest request, UUID userId) {
                Location location = new Location(request, userId); //or Location.from(request, userId); <- static factory method
                this.locationRepository.save(location);
                return new LocationCreateResponse(location); //or LocationCreateResponse.from(location);
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID locationId;

    private String locationName;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

    public Location(LocationCreateRequest request, UUID userId) {
        this.locationId = request.locationId();
        this.locationName = request.locationName();
        this.latitude = request.latitude();
        this.longitude = request.longitude();
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

- It is possible to create and persist entity using a constructor rather than using a setter.
- You can also use static factory method and do not use setter.
- I agree that using setter in the service layer is bad practice.

  - However, I think this problem is related to OOP rather than a problem of strong coupling with JPA.

I hope it will be of help :)